# Joint PMF of $max\{X,Y\}$ and $X$ where $X,Y$ iid geometric

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am interested in finding the joint PFM of $X$, $max\{X,Y\} $ where $X,Y $ are i.i.d geometric random variables with parameter $p$.

My attempt:

$P(X=x,M=m) = P(X=x,M=m,X\geq Y) + P(X=x,M=m, X\lt Y)$

$ = P(X=x=m, X \geq Y) + P(X=x,Y=m,X \lt Y)$

$=P(X=x=m, x  \geq Y) + P(X=x, Y=m, x\lt m)$

=$P(X=x)P(Y \leq x)$ if $x=m$
and $=P(X=x)P(Y=m)$ if $x \lt m$

Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb P(X=k)=(1-p)^{k-1}p = \mathbb P(Y=k)$ for positive integers $k$. Denote by $M=X\vee Y$ the maximum of $X$ and $Y$. Then for any positive integer $m$, we have
$$
\{M=m\} = \{X=m,Y=m\} \cup \{X=m,Y<m\} \cup \{X<m,Y=m\},
$$
and so
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(M=m) &= \mathbb P(X=m,Y=m) + \mathbb P(X=m,Y<m) + \mathbb P(X<m,Y=m)\\
&= \mathbb P(X=m)\mathbb P(Y=m) + \mathbb P(X=m)\mathbb P(Y<m) + \mathbb P(X<m,Y=m)\\
&=(1-p)^{2(m-1)}p^2 + (1-p)^{m-1}p(1 - (1-p)^{m-1}p) + (1 - (1-p)^{m-1}p)(1-p)^{m-1}p\\
&=(p(1-p)^{m-1})^2 + 2 (1-p)^{m-1}p(1 - (1-p)^{m-1}p).
\end{align}